# Images getting corrupted after running python pptx code

Tags: python, powerpoint, corrupt, python-pptx

I am trying to insert some images on slides. But after I run the code, the the images are getting corrupted and a message would appear. I have pasted the message here.:
[image]

The code which i am using is:

```
pic1=prs.slides[1].shapes.add_picture(image_filepath,pre_left,top,width,height);
prs.save(file_path)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can reproduce your problem. This includes a sample input that replicates your error.

Comment: In particular, your code should show the imports used, how you got a `Presentation (prs)` object, and the arguments to the `.add_picture()` call should be replaced with literals as much as possible, such that the provenance of those variables is removed from consideration. Note this will likely mean writing a separate block of code, not just pasting from your existing code. Often this exercise helps you find the error, which is one other reason it's good etiquette. This method is thoroughly tested in the package test suite which means the odds are extremely high it is an error in your code.